# Hooking dynamic/variable named hook in all cases

Tags: hooks

There are numerous dynamically named hooks in WordPress such as `get_transient_$transient` where `$transient` is the name of the transient being retrieved.

How do I hook into this so that my filter is called for all values of `$transient`? Something like `get_transient_*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no global transient filter - you'd either need to know all the transient names you want to target, or you'll have to use the special `all` hook (which runs for *all* actions and filters)

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Thanks for your prompt answer.

Comment: Always worth [submitting a trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/) though ;)

Comment: I was just in the process of doing that when I found there's one already being worked on :)

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24686

Comment: @Monty Nice one!